# Why my effect is running serveral times after action is called?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect that request serveral values to retrive a product from service. Afer dispatch REQUEST_PRODUCTS is called one time as expected, but when I tried go to other location in the routing the this.apiMarketServices is called serveral times, this trigger the router navigate and this will redirect to previous page. The action REQUEST_PRODUCTS is dispatched one time. Why this effect is called serveral times?

Do I need add some kind of stop to the effect in order to avoid the called after the return GetSuccess and GetFailed?

```
@Effect()
   requestProductsFromMarket = this.actions$
   .ofType(REQUEST_PRODUCTS)
   .withLatestFrom(this.store)
   .switchMap(([action, store]) => {
     const id = store.product.id;
     return this.savedProducts.getProduct(id, 'store');
   })
   .switchMap(_ => this.stateService.getMarketId())
   .switchMap(({ marketId }) =>
     this.apiMarketServices.get(MARKETS_PROFILES + marketId)
   )
   .withLatestFrom(this.store)
   .map(([r, store]) => {
     const ser = r.data.map(s => s.legId);
     const storSer =
       store.product.serIds;
     if (storSer.every(s =>ser.includes(s))) {
        this.router.navigate([
          `/products/edit/${store.products.id}`
        ]);
        return GetSuccess;
    } else {
       return GetFailed;
    }
  })
  .catch(() => of(GetQueryFailed));
```

Comment: I can handle with first() operator added after the last switchMap, Promise that is called servaral times, but only works one time. After calling again with a dispatch the effect is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for defect is related to an Observable. In the debugging the "this.apiMarketServices.get(MARKETS_PROFILES + marketId)" was called several times, I realted this services like cause of the defect:

```
.switchMap(({ marketId }) =>
    this.apiMarketServices.get(MARKETS_PROFILES + marketId)
 )
```

But the real cause was the stateSevice, this behavior subject was updated with next, in anothers parts of the app.

```
.switchMap(_ => this.stateService.getMarketId())
```

In order to avoid those calls, I created a function in order to retrive the current value from the BehaviorSubject.

```
getCurrentMarketId(): ClientData {
   return this.currentMarket.value; // BehaviorSubject
 }
```

I added this function to the effect the call is once per  dispatched effect.

```
 ...
 .switchMap(([action, store]) => {
    const id = store.product.id;
    return this.savedProducts.getProduct(id, 'store');
 })
 .map(_ => this.stateService.getCurrentMarketId())
 .switchMap(({ marketId }) =>
    this.apiMarketServices.get(MARKETS_PROFILES + marketId)
 )
```